# Ubuntu 14.04 installation stops when copying files

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, ram

I have the following system config

i5 processor, 
4gb (2+2) ram, 
1gb graphics card, 
500gb hard disk.

I tried adding another 4gb ram to my system. So I added the newly bought 4gb ram into my pc and tried installing clean ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The installation suddenly stops while 'Copying files' process and the system is restarted.

But when I remove the newly added 4gb ram and install, the installation was successful. So after installing the OS, I added the new 4gb ram and my ram config was shown as 7.7gb.

Problem is why I cannot install the OS with all 8gb ram installed?
My 500gb hard disk is empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Issue got resolved when I reinstalled the RAM. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you check your 4gb ram with a tool like`memtest`?

Comment: No. How to do it?

Comment: This is a iso, you should download it from http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm and burn it to a cd or use of a USB flash.

Comment: Okay. Will check it as you have mentioned. How this is going to help?

Comment: So, if your ram is broken, you can use of guarantee or warranty...

Comment: Ubuntu installation images all have memtest, no need to download anything. To use it, hit space (or any key) on boot as soon as the purple background appears. You should then see [this kind of menu](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9QQ7u.png).

Comment: In your case, problem is ram but in some other case it may happen due to faulty hard drive. and to check ram, during boot press shift key, grub menu loading and select `memtest86+`.